# How do you pronounce Korteweg–de Vries

Tags: partial-differential-equations

As stated in the title, how do you pronounce Korteweg-de Vries? I've always just heard it referred to as "KdV" but I have to give a talk on it so I'd like to know how to pronounce it properly.

Comment: "Core-de-veg-de-vrees"

Comment: If you are english speaking then phoeneticaly Core-de-vek de-frees (the de belongs to de Vries).

Comment: @TomCollinge And if I'm not English speaking?

Comment: Looks like you might speak French: bonne chance.

Comment: @TomCollinge I laughed. :)

Comment: If you want to say it in the proper Dutch way, I think it's more like "Korrr-te-ve[insert guttural sound here] de-frees"... (Disclaimer: I'm not Dutch.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnJKI6lKwu0 .....................................

Note: on the question of attempting difficult sounds in languages you do not know: first, a Dutch guy with whom I played soccer for years agreed with me that he would prefer announcers to just say the closest thing they could manage and not overdo it. So, I encourage you to stick to the simplified pronunciation used by the guy in the video. Similarly, I remember teaching a kid whose (first) name was spelled Quyen or something like that, Southeast Asian. He said "just say Quinn" but I was foolish and attempted the real thing. Got it really wrong, and got a huge sneer from the student. In some ways i thought I was trying to be worldly, or bond with the students by saying their names, but now i would say that following their expressed wishes is the more important idea.

On the side it recommended other videos on solitons and KdV, but then Jennifer Lawrence on Chelsea Lately, so i watched that next.

Comment: Maybe not as interesting as Jennifer Lawrence (but a little more relevant):
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrI2-bZ7wpc